# How to get code coverage report when I run tests using java language which tests Go Project code?

Tags: go, code-coverage, test-coverage

I have a very special requirement in integration testing in go. In the past few days I have read through many blogs but I am unable to get the solution for this problem. Please share me if you have done anything below.

Infra details:

- Having Go project up and running
- Having my automation framework written in JAVA

My Exact requirement is:

1. I have to instrument the Go code and make the go code running
2. Execute my java automation code
3. Stop the Go code / get the code coverage report from Go

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Not sure what you're saying, but will this do it for you? https://github.com/jstemmer/go-junit-report

Comment: No , you are giving the solution for the unit testcases and for which there are many ways to do it . I am taking here about integration test of GO from Java Testng code

Answer (score 6):

1. write your Go code as a test, in a file ending_test in the package directory
2. run the Go test as `$ go test --coverprofile outfile` . If it needs to run as a server then add some code to time it out
3. run your additional Java code
4. wait for the timeout
5. use a command like `$ go tool cover -html=outfile -o cover.html` to see the coverage analysis

Answer (score 1):

The [goc](https://github.com/qiniu/goc) tool should meet your needs, it basically just need three steps:

1. launch a services registry center via `goc server` command
2. use `goc build .` to build your Go code and execute the generated binary which would register itself into the registry center above
3. Execute your automation codes, then you can use `goc profile` to get the code coverage profile at anytime